# Run PowerShell in Conemu from context menu

Tags: windows, powershell, contextmenu

I want to run PowerShell from the context menu of folders, disks, files, background catalogs

I tried different options from such questions on this forum, but none works.

Now I have like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMQmg.jpg)

with such a command

```
"D:\PATH\ConEmu64.exe" -inside -config "shell" /REUSE  -dir "%1" -run {powershell} -cur_console:n
```

For example, with such

```
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process powershell  -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command cd %V' -Verb runAs\""
```

Reports that there is no access

Answer (score 2):

This code will set up a Run with PS item in the SendTo menu:

```
Clear-Host

   #Create SendTo Shortcut
 
   $PgmBase = "Run with PS"

   $SendToPath = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\" +
                 "Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\"
                 
   If (!(Test-path -Path "$SendToPath$PgmBase.lnk")) {
     
     $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
     $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut(
                 "$SendToPath\$PgmBase.lnk")
     $Shortcut.TargetPath   = 
      "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"   
     $Shortcut.Arguments    = "-File $Args"
     $Shortcut.WindowStyle  = 7
     $Shortcut.IconLocation = 
      "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
     $Shortcut.Save()
   
     "The $PgmBase option has been added to" +
                "File Explorer SendTo menu."
              
   } #End If (!(Test-Path...

   Else { "Run with PS SendTo shortcut already exists!" }
```

HTH

Comment: Well, I can run not from "Send to"?

Comment: Why can't you use SendTo? It's a standard part of the context menu.